# Pod to pod traffic encryption in fargate EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

Is there a reasonable way to achieve a pod to pod encryption mTLS or normal (one-sided) tls between pods (and also alb->pods) in EKS Fargate?
Let's say the traffic goes via https to ALB, it terminates TLS, but then I still want the traffic to be encrypted going further, same goes for traffic between pods.
Normally it would be done most likely via Service Mesh (Istio,Linkerd or AppMesh), but none of those are supported in Fargate EKS (AppMesh is, but with limitations that seem to disallow using it for TLS between pods).
There are dirty workarounds like deploying nginx sidecar with every pod and distributing self-signed certs between pods manually, and adding the related CA to application trust-stores, but this is really non-prod solution.
Pod to pod traffic encryption in EKS Fargate in 'prod-like' setting - is it even possible?

Comment: I am curious, if you are the point of adding a service mesh to your architecture, what benefit is fargate still providing? Managed node groups have no additional cost.

Comment: I'm not asking for service mesh in particular, just any reasonable approach at all to encrypt traffic between pods on eks fargate (service mesh is just an example on how it's achieved in non-fargate eks, but it's not applicable here).

Let's say the auditor demands pod-to-pod communication to be encrypted - there seems to be no realistic solution on Fargate variant of EKS